# How to deal with Denial of Service attack and Session fixation and Cross Site request forgery in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dns, session

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails.

I happened to look for prevention of DNS attacks in Rails and ended up reading about DNS, Session fixation and Cross Site request forgery in Rails?

How do you prevent all the above three attacks??

Could you suggest me a good tutorial on how to deal with attack in RoR?

Looking forward for your help

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Gautam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSRF: Rails has built-in protection against these attacks that is turned on by default. See [this article](http://m.onkey.org/2007/9/28/csrf-protection-for-your-existing-rails-application).

Session Fixation: [This article](http://www.rorsecurity.info/journal/2007/4/15/session-fixation-in-rails.html) has some decent info.

Denial of Service: Not sure there's anything Rails-specific to be done, but I have almost no experience dealing with these. I just let my outstanding host deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

Basic introduction of denial of service attack http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brJiVE7UTOo